# Run php script behaving like image

Tags: php, image

There is a way I write eg. `http://www.examle.com/hello/image.png` (or in another form, it doesn't matter) and get image with text "hello" in it?

I mean, how to run some php script when loading image (create image "on the fly", no caching) and be able to use it like ordinary image so I can embed it somewhere and everytime the page with image is loaded it loads image with current numbers/stats, whatever.

Something like this banner:
http://cache.www.gametracker.com/server_info/201.4.55.227:29009/b_560_95_1.png

return this:
[image]

Can someone give me a hint how to do that?

EDIT:
I know how to create image, but issue is how to update it (recreate it) when is loaded on website. I need image actually provide "live" data.
One way would be probably using cron jobs and update image "outside" every period of time, in case the name remain same, it would do the trick, although it's not live.

Comment: Yes, it's called [GD](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)

Comment: you will need a mod_rewrite rule to translate that url to something like `script.php?text=hello` and then your php script would grab the text from `$_GET['text']` and build a dynamic image and output image headers and the image. There are tons of tools for both mod_rewrite and dynamically outputting text in an image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use PHP GD: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Example (from http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples-png.php):

```
<?php

header("Content-type: image/png");
$string = $_GET['text'];
$im     = imagecreatefrompng("images/button1.png");
$orange = imagecolorallocate($im, 220, 210, 60);
$px     = (imagesx($im) - 7.5 * strlen($string)) / 2;
imagestring($im, 3, $px, 9, $string, $orange);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

The docs should point you in the right direction.

Comment: That's not the problem. I know how to create image, but how to update it (recreate it) when is loaded on website. I need image actually provide "live" data.

Comment: That's exactly what this does. It uses a base image (`images/button1.png`), but then renders text over the image based on the `text` query parameter. You could use `imagecreatetruecolor()` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php) to start with a blank image instead.

Note that your example probably uses a base image as well.

Comment: Thanks for patience, but still not core of my problem. How run these functions (some php script) when someone access it directly like ...com/image.png - just simple image, no php or anything? I have had great example for it, but can't find it (It is a banner, which shows your user agent, IP etc., I will be still digging) - that's exactly I need. Hope it clear my question :)

Comment: Nevermind, just tried your method and it works fine even there is no .png extension :), feel stupid now, sorry and thanks

Comment: Yes, you can use `mod_rewrite` as suggested by Crayon Violent to redirect if you'd like. But the browser doesn't actually care what the extension is. It looks at the `Content-Type` header, which this script sets to `image/png` (instead of the default, `text/html`).

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I was missing :)